# React and mobx : Use domain class in store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I try to learn the usage of mobx with react and typescript.

And I want to do something but I don't know if it's possible and if it's a good practice.

I want to have a store (in my case GridStore) and a domain class (Grid) like a Service/Entity structure.

I try something like

```
export default class GridStore {
    private rootStore: RootStore;

    @observable grid: Grid;

    constructor(rootStore: RootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
        this.grid = new Grid();
    }

    @action
    select = (x: number, y: number) => {
        // the grid.select change grid's properties which are used in component
        if (this.grid.select(x, y)) {
            // if change do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any results with that.
EDIT: I mean components don't re-render. One more precision in this first example, the class Grid doesn't contain mobx annotation, it's just a class with props and methods.

So I try to use Grid like a store with mobx annotation. And it seems to works a little.

```
// rootStore
export class RootStore {
    gridStore: GridStore;
    grid: Grid;
    constructor() {
        this.grid = new Grid();
        this.gridStore = new GridStore(this);
    }
}

// in GridStore
@action
select = (x: number, y: number) => {
    // the gird.select change grid's properties which are used in component
    if (this.rootStore.grid.select(x, y)) {
            // if change do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

In my mind, the Grid class is just a simple class and not a store. And GridStore has observable Grid property. Is it the right reasoning?
Can I use a thing like my first example? If yes, how? If no, what is good practice?

Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what's the problem? `I don't have any results with that.` what results do you expect with that? Both examples looks fine at the first sight, both should work.

Comment: sorry with `I don't have any results with that.` I mean my component doesn't re-render on Grid change

Comment: Based on your code everything should work fine if you have x and y inside `Grid` and they are marked `@observable` and component is wrapped in `observer`. Maybe you could reproduce it with http://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Yes : 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/SonOfWinter/match3/tree/grid_domain_class/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fstore%2FNewGridStore.ts&theme=dark
Now it's work but not very well ... first interaction ok but the others
One thing i realy want to know is what is the good practice in my case ? Is it ok to use a classe domain like that ?

Comment: Yep, it is totally fine to have domain models inside stores or even other models. Whole libraries are based on this, for example https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree

Comment: OK thanks. I found the solution in fact the class Grid have a property with type Cell[ ] and Cell's properties were not observable. Now it's work fine.

Comment: Yeah, first thing to check when something is not updated is that everything is marked is observable and every component is observer